# XAMPP Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly

Tags: apache, xampp

I am having this error on starting apache in XAMPP localhost, not able to understand it. I have tried changing the default port in httpd.conf, still not working. Here's the error log

```
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:02.742779 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6344:tid 528] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:03.294494 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 6344:tid 528] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:06.655537 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6344:tid 528] AH00455: Apache/2.4.16 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.1p PHP/5.5.28 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:06.655537 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6344:tid 528] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC11 Server built: Jul 12 2015 10:56:48
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:06.655537 2015] [core:notice] [pid 6344:tid 528] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\xampp\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/xampp/apache'
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:06.671166 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6344:tid 528] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 1324
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:08.040905 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1324:tid 536] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:08.322172 2015] [ssl:warn] [pid 1324:tid 536] AH01909: www.example.com:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Tue Sep 29 23:04:08.509695 2015] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 1324:tid 536] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn off SSL (HTTPS) on your server unless you need it.

On XAMP,  Go to config -> apache and choose the httpd.conf file. Save a backup somewhere safe. Then look for the directive:

```
Listen 443
```

Put a # before this to disable SSL. Likewise depending on Xamp, you may have virtual hosts listening on this port. Look for any config blocks listening on 443 (might be *:443) and comment them out.

Final option to check is the SSL engine. This could be in a seperate config file (ssl.conf).

```
SSLEngine on
```

Change it to off.

All of those should disable SSL for you. Unless you need it, in which case there's an issue between your certificate and server config which we can look into.

Comment: there is no Listen 443 in httpd.conf of apache

Comment: You error states `www.example.com:443`, is there an ssl.conf file? Possibly in the `xampp\apache\conf\extra` folder.